# Elegant way of returning [1,0] or [0,1]

Tags: python, performance, size

I'm trying to find an elegant, yet efficient method of outputting `[1,0]` and `[0,1]` depending on a value `v` which can be `0` or `1` respectively.

**To be clear**

```
i/o
0 >>> [1,0]
1 >>> [0,1]
```

Very simple task, though I wonder what the most 'pythonic' way of accomplishing this would be.

**What are your thoughts?**

Comment: So far `[0,1] if v else [1,0]` is my best shot. I'd imagine there's a shorter way perhaps.

Comment: `v and [0, 1] or [1, 0]` would be one character less, but also less clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for readability, I actually like your solution. But you want something shorter:

```
[1-v, v]
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

A few options (no error handling here). I would opt for `g()` or `h()` depending on the situation, and `f()` is silly.

```
PAIRS = {
    0 : [1,0],
    1 : [0,1],
}

def f(n):
    return sorted(range(2), reverse = not n)

def g(n):
    return PAIRS[n]

def h(n):
    return [0,1] if n else [1,0]
```

Comment: I like the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The [bitwise exclusive or (XOR)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) works as well.

```
[v^1, v]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
[(v+1) % 2, v]
```